# One Paypal business account. Two websites with different settings

Tags: paypal

I have this situation.

One Paypal business account.
Two websites.

Both websites have a Standard Payment integration - a HTML form submits to PayPal with products and shipping price.

At the moment I'm being asked to integrate the following changes.

One websites should have delivery price ranges for USA only.
Another should accept payments from Canada only.

As I don't want to integrate IP2Country on my bespoke e-shop solution, is it possible to set such things in PayPal?

- I know you can set delivery price ranges.
- And I know you can ban countries from accepting payments.

However is it possible to target different websites from one PayPal account.
Maybe add another email?

How would you approach this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this via the Payments Pro API, where you just adjust the calls to suit each site's needs. The downside is you would have to have an SSL certificate and more PCI compliance.

Comment: Don't really follow... The problem for me is that I don't want to identify user's country on my servers, I'd like for PayPal to do this for me and use rules set up in PayPal account. Otherwise I don't see different between Payments Pro and Payments Standard. Could you please expand how Payments Pro would help with the problem I have.

Comment: If you control the process (Payments Pro) you'll have this data before they complete checkout and can then take the proper steps (i.e. filter out non-CA users, etc)